# Rails and MInitest stubbing JSON API for blank string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

A Minitest stub is returning an error:

```
JSON::ParserError: 767: unexpected token at ''
  app/controllers/concerns/universal_methods.rb:94:in `do_geocode_lookup'
```

that line in `universal_methods` is the JSON parser

```
results = JSON.parse(response)
```

The stub request comes from Minitest's own suggestion:

```
stub_request(:get, "https://api.[...]").
  with( headers: { 'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby' }).
  to_return(status: 200, body: "", headers: {})
```

If instead I run the action within a block

```
WebMock.disable!
    [...]
WebMock.enable!
```

The test runs through.

What is wrong with the minitest suggested stub?

Comment: Pretty much everything. The JSON parser expects the string to contain at least one octet. Instead of just stubbing in a blank string use something thats actually valid JSON (such as a "canned" response from the API). The VCR gem is useful for this.

Comment: Its hard to really give you more advice here without seeing the code under test but there are a lot of red flags here - what you're doing most likely does not belong in a concern (especially not one with such a fluffy name). 
Instead you should create one object that touches the application boundry (the client) which handles communicating with the api and another which handles integrating it into your API. Just shoving this away into a concern makes your controller very fat - in disguise.

Comment: Also the suggestion has nothing to do with minitest - thats webmock. And its not meant to be taken verbatim. Its a generic message for any type of unstubbed request.